# Sorting in cakephp pagination with SR.NO instead of Database ID

Tags: cakephp, sorting, pagination, cakephp-2.0

Hi guys i have a problem regarding cakephp pagination and sorting

I have setup a paginated view as flows

SR.NO | name | address| phone|...

SR.NO is a simple counter with-in the foreach loop for displaying data instead of database ID

The below link shows how my SR.NO is created

[CakePHP: Numbered Paginated Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366315/cakephp-numbered-paginated-results)

All is fine till now...

Now i have a requirement to sort the result based on SR.NO but have no idea on how to achieve this...

Pour some light into my head thanks...

Comment: If you're really only talking about max ~100 rows, you could try a javascript table sorter.

Comment: @Dave hmmm....that can do it...but maybe i will have to follow the same pattern for bigger tables also , so i need a cakey way to do this...

Comment: u fill do this by simple find query like that     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
$number=mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "Total records in Student table= ". $number;  and pass in serion no an id, which u can make CRUD, if u want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366315/cakephp-numbered-paginated-results look also there

Comment: @usii thats exactly what i did...but my problem is to sort it by the SR.NO....display works fine....

Comment: u can sort the data with id, but if u do with the serial no u can send hidden id for example if student is 16 and serial no is 1 so in behalf of 1 u can sort 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, S.NO is just the row-number in the results, and added with PHP.

If the query does *not* sort the result and S.NO has no relation with the data from the database, you **cannot** sort on this column, **and it would not make any sense to do so.**

#### Explanation

SQL queries without an 'ORDER BY xxx' will return the results in a **random order**; [SQL Server UNION - What is the default ORDER BY Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour)

Basically, this means that every time you run the query, the results may come back in a different order.

The S.NO you're adding is based on the order in which the results came back from your query, but because this order is *random*, each time you view the same page, the *same* record may get *another* position, thus another S.NO

#### Options

Specify a column to sort the results on so that the order of the results is consistent each time. You'll be able to *reverse* the sort-order as well if desired. S.NO can still be used, but purely for *presentation*

Alternatively, calculate the row position using SQL ([Get row position in MYSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057772/get-row-position-in-mysql-query)). However, even in this case row number is based on the position of each row in the results. If *no* `ORDER BY` is present, row number is still 'random' and the same row may get a different S.NO / row number each time the query is executed.

The final option is to sort using JavaScript (as others suggested). **however**, also because of the 'random' order, this can only be done for the records that are visible on the page. If you're using pagination (page x of y), sorting the entire database table will require a new query on the database (which cannot be ordered because of the whole 'random' issue)

Comment: so i guess there's  not much choice i will follow option 1. thankz for this neat explanation...

Comment: You're welcome, sorry that I could offer no alternative, but this *is* the situation. Unless there's a 'real' S.NO in the database, the order is just random. You might consider to store a calculated 'S.NO' field in the database. However, for that you'll also have to consider "what is the S.NO order based on?"